# Angular - Unit Testing Modal Factory Call

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to verify that a factory function is called from within a modal function, if passed a valid file object. The factory is injected into the modal controller and when the test is run the factory is undefined. What is the proper way to test that a factory function is called from within a modal?

***modal controller***

```
  angular.module('vicModule')
  .controller('vicModalController', vicModalController);

  vicModalController.$inject = [
    '$uibModalInstance',
    '$uibModal',
    'utilFunctionsFactory'
  ]

  function vicModalController($uibModalInstance, $uibModal, utilFunctionsFactory) {
    mvm.uploadVICs = uploadVICs;

    function uploadVICs(file, error) {
      if (file == null) {
        data.errorMessage = 'file is not found or not supported';
        return;
      }
      if(error.length > 0) {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
        data.errorMessage = 'reading file error';
        return;
      } else {
        var fileData = utilFunctionsFactory.validateCSV(file, error);
      }
    }
  }
```

***modal controller test***

```
describe('vicModalController', function() {
  var $controller, vicModalController, vicFactory, utilFunctionsFactory, $q, $scope, $httpBackend, deferred, $uibModalInstance;
  beforeEach(module('fotaAdminPortal'));
  beforeEach(module('vicModule'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _vicFactory_, _utilFunctionsFactory_, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    vicFactory = _vicFactory_;
    utilFunctionsFactory: _utilFunctionsFactory_;
    $q = _$q_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $uibModalInstance = { // Create a mock object using spies
      close: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.close'),
      dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.dismiss'),
      result: {
        then: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.result.then')
      }
    };
    vicModalController = $controller('vicModalController', {
      vicFactory: vicFactory,
      utilFunctionsFactory: utilFunctionsFactory,
      $uibModalInstance: $uibModalInstance
    });
  }));
  it('should be defined', function() {
    expect(vicModalController).toBeDefined();
  });
  describe('uploadVICS()', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function(_utilFunctionsFactory_) {
      utilFunctionsFactory = _utilFunctionsFactory_;
      spyOn(utilFunctionsFactory, 'validateCSV').and.callFake(function() {
        return {};
      });
    }));
    it('should call validateCSV() with valid file', function() {
      vicModalController.uploadVICs({}, []);
      expect(utilFunctionsFactory.validateCSV()).toHaveBeenCalledWith({}, []);
    });
  });
});
```

***edit***

I had the assignment wrong in the beforeEach:

utilFunctionsFactory: *utilFunctionsFactory*; //incorrect colon
utilFunctionsFactory = *utilFunctionsFactory*; // should be assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues I see:

You are doing:

```
utilFunctionsFactory: _utilFunctionsFactory_;
```

instead of:

```
utilFunctionsFactory = _utilFunctionsFactory_;
```

Also you are asserting that the result of `validateCSV` is called:

```
expect(utilFunctionsFactory.validateCSV()).toHaveBeenCalledWith({}, []);
```

Instead of `validateCSV` itself:

```
expect(utilFunctionsFactory.validateCSV).toHaveBeenCalledWith({}, []);
```

Comment: You are correct, though I already figured it out. Thanks anyways!